# Merge free space partition back to main volume

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, partition

Can someone guide me how to merge my "free space" to main partition and how to delete and merge other unnecessary partitions? [image]

Comment: Please search before posting - https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=ffffffff

Comment: What "unnecessary" partitions do you see there that you need to delete, other than disk0s3?

Comment: Can you post the output from the command `diskutil info disk0s3 | grep -e Size -e Offset`. Note: you probably will not be able to restart your Mac without first repairing the GUID Partition Table (GPT).

Comment: @MarcWilson I can see 29.9Gb of free space. As well as the strange APFS container name which is referenced in 145 other questions!